# Python - Joining floating point numbers within list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, join

I have a list of strings such as this:

```
L = [['(', '11', '.', '253920135318836', '-', '12' ')', '+', '3','.','12']]
```

Currently, when I am printing out the list as shown above, it is printing out "(", "11" and the rest of the list is not being printed out. Is there a way that this can be fixed as I want to be able to make it in the form:

```
[['(', '11.253920135318836', '-', '12' ')', '+' ,'3.12']]
```

but am struggling to make it in this way
Thank you!

Comment: What? How is the list not printed when you print the list? What exactly are you doing? Show us the code.

Comment: Btw you have a list with one element which is a list of strings.

Comment: what you want ?? joining floating point numbers or removing strings those are not float ?

Comment: why are you creating the list in this way `L = [['(', '11', '.', '253920135318836', '-', '12' ')', '+', '3','.','12']]` before creation can you handle ??

Comment: Can you post the code that is failing?

Comment: I think all you want to do is combine floating point numbers into a single entry, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would join it together into one string, then split it on parens, and `+`/`-`:

```
>>> import re
>>> L = [['(', '11', '.', '253920135318836', '-', '12' ')', '+', '3','.','12']]

>>> [re.split('([\(\)\+\-])', ''.join(sublist)) for sublist in L]
[['', '(', '11.253920135318836', '-', '12', ')', '', '+', '3.12']]
```

As @StevenRumbalski noted, we can filter out the empty values:

```
>>> [filter(None, (re.split('([\(\)\+\-])', ''.join(sublist))) for sublist in L]
[['(', '11.253920135318836', '-', '12', ')', '+', '3.12']]
```

Someone better with regex might have a different suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

They say (heck, I say) that you shouldn't change a list while iterating over it. Sometimes that's exactly what you want to do. When this code sees a period, it reaches ahead to combine the next list item with the previous  item, and trims the list so that it doesn't process the next item a second time. Add a recursive call to handle sublists and you've got your glue code.

```
L = [['(', '11', '.', '253920135318836', '-', '12' ')', '+', '3','.','12']]

def glue_floats(alist):
    try:
        newlist = alist[:]
        for i, val in enumerate(newlist):
            if isinstance(val, list):
                # recursively handle sublists
                newlist[i] = glue_floats(val)
            elif val == '.':
                # combine -1 to +1 inclusive and shrink for next iteration
                newlist[i-1:i+2] = [''.join(newlist[i-1:i+2])]
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError('float missing component')
    return newlist

print(glue_floats(L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['(', '11', '.', '253920135318836', '-', '12' ')', '+', '3','.','12']
res =[]
temp = ''
for i in ''.join(lst):
   if i in '+-*/()':
      if temp:res.append(temp)
      res.append(i)
      temp = ''
   else:
      temp += i
res.append(temp)

print res

['(', '11.253920135318836', '-', '12', ')', '+', '3.12']
```